# Implementation of validation and Cancel Validation Flows in Business Process using bpm (BonitaBpm)

Tags: process, workflow, business-process-management, bonita, orchestration-step

I am currently working on a business process that involves orchestrating steps with validation and cancel validation requirements. I need to have the ability to validate a step and pass to next task(s) or cancel its validation (undo the next task(s) and go back to previous task).

Given this scenario, I'm seeking guidance on how to design the cancellation functionality using BPM. How can I appropriately handle the cancellation process in the following example?

[Business process example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReTsp.png)

I have tried to handle this issue by conditioning each transition whether the task is validated or cancelled, but the process became to much complicated and not maintainable by the final client.

I have tried to handle this issue by adding conditions to each transition in order to determine whether proceed to next task(s) if the task was validated or go back if the task was cancelled. However, this approach has resulted in a complicated and difficult-to-maintain process for the final client (the client should have the ability to change the order of steps of remove some of them).
[Cancellation diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKyEL.png)

**Note**: the given process is just portion of the real process